# Relleno automatico de celdas por mes

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo un base de datos en la cual tengo los datos de los viajes, conductores y tarifas, y me gustaría automatizar una planilla de remuneraciones donde solo se vayan agregando los servicios por nombre de conductor + tarifa modificada para ellos, ej:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quizás con un lista desplegable elegir el mes y con un buscarv que se vaya rellenando, no sé. Si alguien tiene alguna idea de que podría utilizar o si hay que ocupar VBA, todo sirve :(

Comment: Para empezar.. no tenes una base de datos.. tenes una planilla de calculo.. que ponele, funciona como base de datos... ahora, hay mil formas de hacer esto... pero nadie lo va a hacer por vos aca.. asi que si tenes un intento y un codigo que te trae problemas, con gusto te vamos a ayudar...

Comment: Deberías poner ejemplos que se puedan copiar y pegar, los puedes hacer con [Table Markdown Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables). De igual manera, como dice @gbianchi, tienes que poner cómo funciona paso a paso lo que quieres hacer y qué has intentado para hacerlo.